# Using Redux Toolkit Query hooks in class components

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

We have a really large codebase with 271 class components and the old redux (not redux toolkit).

We are in the process of migrating to redux toolkit - and adoption RTK-Query as our async state manager. We will migrate redux-saga based functionality to rtk-query and trim our reducers.

For functional components it's very easy to do both things

1. get data, loading state
2. dispatch the action to ask for this data.

```
 const {data: posts, isLoading, isError, isSuccess } = usePosts();
```

But how do I do this in a class based component...

```
componentDidMount(){
  //what to dispatch here ?
}

render(){
   const {data: posts, isLoading, isError, isSuccess } = fromWhichPlace;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We specifically cover this topic in our docs:

- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/usage-without-react-hooks
- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#react-class-components

Per those pages, you'd need to do something along the lines of:

```
const mapState = (
  state: RootState,
  ownProps: RouteComponentProps<{ id: string }>
) => ({
  id: Number(ownProps.match.params.id),
  post: endpoints.getPost.select(Number(ownProps.match.params.id))(state),
  updatePostState: endpoints.updatePost.select(ownProps.match.params.id)(state), // TODO: make selectors work with the requestId of the mutation?
  deletePostState: endpoints.updatePost.select(ownProps.match.params.id)(state)
});

const mapDispatch = {
  getPost: endpoints.getPost.initiate,
  updatePost: endpoints.updatePost.initiate,
  deletePost: endpoints.deletePost.initiate
};

const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch);
type PostDetailProps = ConnectedProps<typeof connector> & RouteComponentProps;

export class PostDetailComp extends React.Component<PostDetailProps> {
  state = {
    isEditing: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id, getPost } = this.props;
    getPost(id);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: PostDetailProps) {
    const { id, getPost } = this.props;
    if (id !== prevProps.id) {
      getPost(id);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { isEditing } = this.state;
    const {
      // state
      id,
      post: { data: post, isLoading: isPostLoading },
      updatePostState: { isLoading: isUpdateLoading },
      deletePostState: { isLoading: isDeleteLoading },

      // actions
      updatePost,
      deletePost
    } = this.props;

    // snip rendering logic
}

export const PostDetail = connector(PostDetailComp);
```

However, **we would *strongly* recommend that you convert these components to function components instead, and use the auto-generated query hooks!**  It will be *much* simpler and easier to use, and the hooks have a lot of built-in functionality that will be hard to replicate by hand in class components.

Comment: well, we have 271 class components and although I do re-write every class to FC where-ever possible - convincing everyone else is a major problem

Comment: You don't have to rewrite _every_ component right away :)  But I can seriously tell you that the work of rewriting the components that need this data to be function components using query hooks will be less effort than trying to manage the RTKQ subscriptions yourself in class components.